# Android Studio Gradle Configuration with name 'default' not found using library project shinobicharts

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

*settings.gradle*:

```
include ':app'
include ':app:libraries:shinobicharts-android-library'
```

*build.gradle*:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rohit2906.myhistogram"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project('libraries:shinobicharts-android-library')
}
```

I am trying to add library project which is shinobicharts-android-library and it is in libraries folder.Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a build.gradle for each module in your project.

Also it is not a good idea to define a module inside another module.

You should have this structure:

```
root
  app
    build.gradle
  libraries
    shinobicharts-android-library
       build.gradle
  build.gradle   //top level
  settings.gradle
```

In your `settings.gradle` change in:

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries:shinobicharts-android-library'
```

In your `app/build.gradle` change

```
compile project(':libraries:shinobicharts-android-library')
```

In `shinobicharts-android-library/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 21
   buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

   defaultConfig {
     minSdkVersion 11
     targetSdkVersion 21
   }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //...other
}
```

Comment: what should be there in my build.gradle of the library directory

Comment: Same parameters as application. compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, defaultConfig, dependencies...

Comment: So which build.gradle i shud copy to the new build.gradle which i will add to the library project

Comment: Can u provide me with the exact build.gradle which i can copy as it is in the libraries directory

Comment: @ROHITKUMARDUBEY Updated with an example, but it depends by your code and dependencies