# Using the android studio project as library in the main activity

Tags: android, android-library

I am trying to use shinobicharts as a library for my project app. . I am getting error when I import the library classes.Please help me to sort this out.
the project goes as

```
app
    manifest
    ....
    ....
shinobicharts-android-library
   manifest
```

I am using following import statements to import charts and other classes from my library.

```
import com.shinobicontrols.charts.Chart;
import com.shinobicontrols.charts.Dock;
import com.shinobicontrols.charts.axis.XAxis;
import com.shinobicontrols.charts.axis.YAxis;
import com.shinobicontrols.charts.data.XYDataSeries;
import com.shinobicontrols.charts.data.item.XYDataSeriesItem;
import com.shinobicontrols.charts.data.item.implementation.XYDataSeriesItemImpl;
import com.shinobicontrols.charts.series.Line;
```

but it colors chart, dock,axis all in red and doesnot recognise them.Please help.
here is my app.gradle yes I have mentioned it.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rohit2906.myhistogram"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project('libraries:shinobicharts-android-library')
}
```

Comment: did you mention in your app.gradle that you want a library in your project

Comment: yes I have posted app.gradle. I have mentioned that I think

Comment: well naruto is not coming today, is there any documentation for "libraries:shinobicharts-android-library", this might solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998627/android-studio-gradle-configuration-with-name-default-not-found-using-library

Comment: No I have already added it as my library project ,I just want to know how to use that.

Comment: did you make a lib directory and then copied jar in that

Comment: Please show your project folder structure then i will give you gradle code

Comment: I converted a studio project into library not the jar into library.